# php application working on local not on live/production server

Tags: php

I  have an attendance management system  application written with PHP. The package works fine on my local machine but when I tried to host it on a production server, the home page is loading but I'm not able to login with any user account/data.

```
<?php 

session_start();
include_once("include\config.php");
if (isset($_POST['textfield1'])&&isset($_POST['textfield2'])){
$login = $_POST["textfield1"];
$pwd = $_POST["textfield2"];
$recordset = mysql_query("select * from users");

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($recordset)){
    if($login == $record["ulogin"] && $pwd == $record["upassword"]) 
    {

    $_SESSION["ulogin"] = $record["ulogin"];
    $_SESSION["uid"] = $record["uid"];  
            if($record["utype"] == 1){
            $_SESSION["utype"] = $record["utype"];
            header("Location:admin.php?uid=".$record["uid"]);
            exit;
            }else{
        header("Location:home.php");
        exit;
        }
   }
} 
}
header("Location:login.php?invalid=1");  
?>
```

This is my user password verification code
base connection. Everything works fine. Please help me out.

Comment: is there any DB on server?

Comment: check your config.php whether you have given live server's details like hostname, username, password & Dbname

Comment: Small site note: for `Location` header actually an absolute URL is recommended. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: Is users table having same data both on local and remote servers?

Comment: thanks all for the reply yes i have configured my config.php and given all d details correctly tis is my db connection settings  $dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = ' ';
$dbname = ' ';
$dbpass = ' ';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn);

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ yes it was same data in both local and server

Comment: @Jona then i have to give the url in the location rather than file location m i right

Answer (score 0):

Confirm DB is on server. Confirm your config. One quick MYSQL tip(if you are using it): if information_schema table shows, then you DB is not properly configured.

Comment: my db is in server and connection is fine no error is connection but i m unable to login in